# Turtle giving no response

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've been trying to make a racing game between 3 turtle cursors and I created a function for each of them to move forward 5 pixels until they reach the top of the canvas. However, when ran, the turtles stayed idle and I can't figure out why.

```py
import turtle
import random

Bank_account = 0


class turtle_s:

    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
        self.turt = turtle.Pen()
        self.turt.shape('turtle')
        self.turt.color(color)


red_turtle = turtle_s('red')
blue_turtle = turtle_s('blue')
yellow_turtle = turtle_s('yellow')

turtle_list = [red_turtle, blue_turtle, yellow_turtle]


## Turtle Game Setup
def turtle_stuff():

    turtle.screensize(canvwidth=500, canvheight=500)
    turtle.bgcolor('black')

    for color_turtle in turtle_list:

        if turtle_list.index(color_turtle) % 3 == 0:

            color_turtle.turt.penup()
            color_turtle.turt.setpos(-300, -250)
            color_turtle.turt.left(90)

        elif turtle_list.index(color_turtle) % 3 == 1:

            color_turtle.turt.penup()
            color_turtle.turt.setpos(300, -250)
            color_turtle.turt.left(90)

        else:

            color_turtle.turt.penup()
            color_turtle.turt.setpos(0, -250)
            color_turtle.turt.left(90)


def turtle_move():

    for color_turtle in turtle_list:

        color_turtle.turt.speed(random.randint(3, 5))

        while color_turtle.turt.ycor() != 250:

            color_turtle.turt.forward(5)
turtle_stuff()
turtle_move()
```

Comment: The code you posted won't work: what is the `self.turt = turtle.Pen()` line intended for? `Pen` is a method of a `Turtle` object, not of the `turtle` module. More important, I don't see where you _create_ your turtles

Comment: Ah I see. You're right :-)

Comment: @gimix I wanted each of the class objects (the turtles) to also be a turtle pen. 

I created my turtles right under the class I made

Comment: Those are not turtles. They are just instance of a similarly named class. Perhaps you wanted your class to be a subclass of `Turtle`, or to have an attribute referencing a `Turtle`; but that's not what the code does

Comment: @SkepT1cal please forget all I said. There was an issue in my Python install (the `turtle` module was a customized version) and it didn't recognize `Pen` as an alias for `Turtle`, so it kept giving me an error. But now that I fixed it your code runs for me - the turtles get created and do the movements as expected

Comment: @gimix haha all good.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, the turtles don't stay idle as you describe.  But what they unfortunately do is run the race completely in turn, not at the same time.  This has to do with the structure of your nested loops in `turtle_move()`.  Let's rework your code to simplify it, fix the above issue, and address some style issues:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

class racing_turtle:

    def __init__(self, color):
        self.turtle = Turtle()
        self.turtle.shape('turtle')
        self.turtle.color(color)

racer_list = [racing_turtle('red'), racing_turtle('blue'), racing_turtle('green')]

def racers_setup():
    for offset, racer in enumerate(racer_list, -1):
        racer.turtle.penup()
        racer.turtle.setheading(90)
        racer.turtle.setpos(offset * 300, -250)

def racers_move():
    while True:
        for racer in racer_list:
            distance = randint(2, 6)
            racer.turtle.forward(distance)
            if racer.turtle.ycor() > 250:
                racer.turtle.pencolor('gold')
                break
        else:  # no break
            continue

        break

screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(canvwidth=500, canvheight=500)
screen.bgcolor('black')

racers_setup()
racers_move()

screen.mainloop()
```